# Access: Adding records with identical data, except for ID

Tags: forms, ms-access, record, bulk

I would like to be upfront. I am by no means an expert or even really all that technologically savy. However, I inherited a training system where the only way to find out if someone was current was to dig through physical file cabinets and try to find the hard copy. I have put together a basic access database to try and improve the situation. It is working okay, but I've run into a problem.

Previously, most training occurred in small enough batches that data entry is not a problem. (No more than 15-20 entries at any one time). However, regulatory changes now mandate the company put everyone through a mandated training course annually. This means all information about the training will be identical, except for the employee ID associated with the record.

Right now I can manually enter this training just like any other, but I have to perform this nearly identical data entry for each of the several hundred employees in the company.

I would like to be able to enter the pertinent details about the training and then have access create an training record for each employee.

The current form asks the user:

1. Who is the employee that was trained? (The appropriate employee ID # is entered)
2. Which subject was trained on? (the appropriate selection is made via combo box)
3. On what date was the training completed? Date picker is used to fill.
4. What is the file path to the scanned training certificate? (The majority of this field is prepopulated so only the actual file name needs to be typed. For the specific training in question all the employees of the company will be included in the same scanned pdf. Subsequently, this filed will be identical for all employees.)

The fields on the current form are:

- txtEmpID – Text box, where employee ID # is entered. Corresponds to
  field "empID"
- cboTask – Combo box, where the appropriate training
  subject is selected. Corresponds to field "reqID"
- txtDate – Text box,    the date the training was completed.
  Corresponds to field "trngDate"
- txtFilePath – Text box, file path to the scanned pdf of the physical 
  training record. Corresponds to field "trngLocat"

I would like to be able to fill in the information for 2-4 but then have access create a record, for each employee in my employees table, where all the data from 2-4 is identical.

Is this possible?

Pertinent Tables:

- tblEmployees – keyed on field “empID” which is the employee number.
- tblTrngSubjects - Keyed on field "reqID" which is autonumber.
- tblTrngRec – keyed on field “recordID” which is autonumber. Relates
  to tblEmployees through field “empID”. Relates to tblTrngSubjects
  through field "reqID".

tblTrngRec is the table in which the records will be stored.

Other information that may be relevant: 
I am using Access 2016. 
I once had a copy of Access 2010 the missing manual…but that was in 2010. It has been almost a decade since I did anything more advanced than “docmd.openform”
I greatly appreciate any and all advice. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: You are looking to write a Insert statement to table tblTrngRec.

Answer (score 0):

I admit I haven't worked with access in quite some time, so some of the syntax might be slightly off. You need to know a list of employee IDs that were in that training.

```
Insert into tblTrngRec(empID,ReqID,txtDate,txtFilePath)
select empID
   ,25 'You need to enter this manually
   ,"6/9/2020" 'You need to enter this manually
   ,"Enter your file path"
from tblEmployees
where EmpID IN (enter a comma delimited list of employee IDs)
```